# firebase - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to setup firebase and firestore in my vue app.
I've created a folder named `firebase` inside the src of my project and inside it I've a file named `init.js`

I've this code inside the file, but I'm unable to start the firebase ui from my login component

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'

const config = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: "...firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "...firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "..",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
}


const app = initializeApp(config)
const db = getFirestore()
const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(app)


export { db, ui }
```

When I'm importing the `ui` const in my component I will get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')`

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#access-firebase), you need to pass the Firebase App object (i.e. `app`) to the `getFirestore()` method.

```
const app = initializeApp(config)
const db = getFirestore(app)
```

Comment: I've tested and it's working if I want to see a document but if I try to get all the contents I get an error about permissions